# numbered grid jquery mobile css

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, grid

I'd like to create a numbered grid.The user puts in the number and the grid is generated. I'd like to do it in CSS, HTML or Jquery Mobile. This is for an ipad project. I'm not sure how to approach the problem. I would like the following result:
[image: numbered grid that is auto generated]

As it stands now, I have a div that repeats a grid image across the page. I have to regenerate an image for each background. i.e.: user wants a 40X60 feet area, I will have to generate a 40X60 image. (100px=5 feet on the grid) I'd much rather have the user input two numbers and have the grid and numbers auto generated.

```
<div style="background-image:url(/images/linegrid100.png);
width:980px;height:700px;
border:1px solid black;padding:10px;">
```

I've looked at a serious number of grid generators. I've thought about using a table rather than an image. Would that be better? How do I approach the math for the number generation? Seems like this should all be pretty straight forward, but I can't find much information. (Googled for a couple of days now) These kinds of grids are done all of the time in graphics programs and CAD programs.

Any help would be appreciated.

TIA -Rachel

---

OK. Here is the result of your code. It is running :-) but not as expected.  I've been working with the code all day. It is making more sense now, but I'm still lost with the loops and math. Any ideas? So nice to have help and this is fun. Thanks again -R

The code that seems to impact things is :

```
w = parseInt($square.css('width'), 10) + 2; //the width of each square + 2 pixels for the borders;
```

If I leave it just as you have it:
[image]

If I change the 10 to 100:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume you have the following form where users enter the two numbers:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="x">
    <input type="text" id="y">
</form>
```

Then you can use jQuery to generate your grid as follows:

```
var x = parseInt($('#x').val(), 10),
    y = parseInt($('#y').val(), 10);

grid(x, y);

function grid(x, y) {
   var i = -1,
       j = -1,
       step = 5, //assuming that each grid unit = 5
       $grid = $('<div>', {'id':'grid'}),
       $square = $('<div>', {'class':'square'}),
       $label,
       w = parseInt($square.css('width'), 10) + 2; //the width of each square + 2 pixels for the borders;

  $grid.width(w * x);

  while(++i < x) {
       while(++j < y) {
        if(j === 0) {
        $label = $('<span>', {'class':'label'});
        $label.css('top', j * w).css('left', i * w).html(i * step);
        }
        if(i === 0 && j > 0) {
            $label = $('<span>', {'class':'label'});
        $label.css('top', j * w).css('left', i * w).html(j * step);
            }
            $grid.append($square.clone(), $label);
       }
       j = -1;
  }
  $('body').append($grid);
}
```

CSS:

```
#grid { overflow: hidden; border-left: 1px solid #000; border-top: 1px solid #000; position: relative; }
div.square { width: 50px; height: 50px; float: left; border-bottom: 1px dotted #000; border-right: 1px dotted #000; }
span.label { position: absolute; background: #fff; font-weight: bold; z-index: 10; }
```

Let's say here's our overlay (dialog box):

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="x">
    <input type="text" id="y">
    <button id="build-grid" type="button">Build grid</button>
</div>
```

Then, you attach an onclick event to the build-grid button. So, when the button is clicked, we read the x and y values and build the grid.

```
$('#build-grid').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var x = parseInt($('#x').val(), 10), //get our values from the input fields
       y = parseInt($('#y').val(), 10);

   grid(x, y); // build the grid
});
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you. @Petemk. I can hardly wait to try this out. You are a genius. :-) Rachel

Comment: @petemk Ok. I tried this but it isn't working for me. I'm sure that is because I am not very familiar with jQuery. Pretty new to everything, but how do I get the grid to show up? Do I need to apply the grid id to another page? I've tried using a canvas, also a content area, but when I type in two numbers in the form and hit enter after the last number, nothing happens. Will you walk me through it--like a baby. I'm sorry. --Rachel

Comment: ok, first of all, do you want the two input fields to be on the same page as the grid or not?

Comment: @petemk. No, I am thinking about a dialogue box or a slide out menu, but for the purposes of this. Maybe a popup box would help me to understand. I haven't used forms before so maybe that is where I need to concentrate my learning for this. I have been looking at your code and trying to understand how to access it. Thank you again for doing all of this work and helping me to understand. -Rachel

Comment: @petemk If it would be easier to put the form on the same page for the purposes of helping me understand, that would be great. Please do whatever is easiest for you. Once I see how it is done, I can study it and tweak it later as I progress. Thanks again -Rachel

Comment: @petemk Hi again. I'm making progress! The code is running. Please see my edit above to get an idea of what is now happening. -R

Comment: Why did you change 10 to 100? 10 indicates the numeral system to be used. So, 100 means a numeral system with the base 100, which does not exist.

Comment: @petemk See the first image above? That is how the grid prints if I leave the code in the exact way that you gave it to me. The second image is the way it prints when the 10 is changed to 100. I read that the 10 was for decimals, but just tried changing the number to see if I could get the grid to print out correctly. It was closer, but not correct. Grid is inputed as 40X40, but shows text units through 60 with an odd 195 at the ending column. Maybe I need to go back to using an image. I would like to understand this though.